# Maven - Can't find transitive dependency of 3rd party jar in war

Tags: maven, jboss

I've installed a 3rd party jar in my local maven repository using

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

so I can use that jar in my war project. This jar has the following dependency on its **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I am able to successfully compile and generate the war. But when I deploy it in Jboss 7, I get the following runtime error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/infinispan/manager/DefaultCacheManager
```

Which is a class that I should find in transitive dependency **infinispan-core**. Why is this transitive dependency not being included in my war?

Answer (score 0):

This [JBoss issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-5535?focusedCommentId=13076005&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13076005) mentions:

> Can we see your `MANIFEST.MF` and `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` ?
>
> Infinispan jar files are not automatically exported to WildFly deployments and you need to explicitly add them as dependencies using the techniques described at "[Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)"